# Conditionally output a part of SCSS rule selector

Tags: sass, node-sass

I would like to specify an additional default shortcut class to a set of classes, similarly to that

```
@each $pos, $some-css-rules in ("left": ..., "right": ..., ...) {

  @if $pos == "left" {
    .block,
  }

  .block-#($pos) {
     ...
  }
}
```

that would be outputted as

```
.block,
.block-left {
  ...
}

.block-right {
  ...
}
```

However, it will stumble over `.block,` syntax error.

`.block-left` cannot be replaced here with `.block.left` because `$pos` will collide with existing classes (`.left`, etc).

I would prefer to avoid `.block { @extend .block-left }` if possible, there is a considerable amount of similar rules that will gain a lot of WET code this way.

Is there a way to conditionally output a part of rule selector? How can both SCSS and CSS be kept DRY in a pattern like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but I achieve the output CSS based on your code. I put the @if directive inside the selector to compare with `$pos` variable. Here is my code:

**SASS**

```
@each $pos, $some-css-rules in ("left": red, "right": blue) {
  .block-#{$pos} {
  @if $pos == "left" {
    @at-root .block, &{
    color:$some-css-rules;
    }
  } 
    @else{
      color:$some-css-rules;
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
.block, .block-left {
  color: red;
}

.block-right {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, @at-root does the trick. There is WET ruleset, `color:$some-css-rules`, but I guess it should be treated with a mixin here.